# Installing new gentoo kernel in docker container

Tags: kernel, docker, openvpn, gentoo

I am creating a new docker container to run OpenVpn in Gentoo OS. To make this I need configure the kernel with tun/tap module and install it:

> cd /usr/src/linux
>
> make menuconfig
>
> Device Drivers --->
>   Network device support --->
>
> [*]Network device support
>
> Universal TUN/TAP device driver support  // This option must be
>   enabled
>
> cd /usr/src/linux make && make modules_install

Now I need to install this kernel in the container and continue with the openVPN installation but not know how I do it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker work using the kernel of the host machine.

If you want specific kernel capabilities you need to modify the host kernel.

Then run your container using `--privileged` attribute or using the `--lxc-conf` parameter.